# MySQL - How do i make my query to do this?

Tags: mysql, subquery

What I want to do is order question by similarities/likeness then get
results from `Result` table based on their points from  `Point` table.

**Example**: query = 'Germany location'

**I have the following tables:**

Table Question

```
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
| ques_id  | question                                                   |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
|     1    |  Where is Germany located                                  |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
|     2    |  where is Germany located on a map                         |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
|     3    |  where is Germany located in Europe                        |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
```

Table Result

```
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
| resu_id  | result                                                     |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
|     1    |  Germany is located in Europe                              |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
|     2    |  Northern hemisphere in Europe                             |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
|     3    |  between France & Poland                                   |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
|     4    |  Germany is located in central Europe                      |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
|     5    |  South of Denmark                                          |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
|     6    |  52 degrees North, 13 degrees East                         |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
|     7    |  located on the continent of Europe                        |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
```

Table Point

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| pont_id |  ques_id  |  resu_id  |  point    |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|    1    |     2     |     6     |    10     |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|    2    |     1     |     1     |    8      |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|    3    |     2     |     7     |    7      |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|    4    |     3     |     5     |    9      |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|    5    |     3     |     4     |    8      |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|    6    |     1     |     7     |    10     |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|    7    |     3     |     2     |    6      |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|    8    |     2     |     3     |    4      |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

i tried to

```
SELECT resu_id FROM `Point` WHERE ques_id is (**?**) ORDER BY `point`
```

**Expecting result**

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
| ques_id |  resu_id  |  point    |    result                                  |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|    1    |     7     |     10    |    located on the continent of Europe      |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|    1    |     1     |     8     |    Germany is located in Europe            |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|    2    |     6     |     10    |    52 degrees North, 13 degrees East       |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|    2    |     7     |     7     |    located on the continent of Europe      |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|    2    |     3     |     4     |    between France & Poland                 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|    3    |     5     |     9     |    South of Denmark                        |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|    3    |     4     |     8     |    Germany is located in central Europe    |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|    3    |     2     |     6     |    Northern hemisphere in Europe           |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

sort questions by relevance, then respective result based on point value.

Thanks all for help, don't be harsh on me :)

Comment: If you tried, what was wrong in the results? Are you looking for result id of the correct answer or a list of result ids for the question id in a specific order?

Comment: @Ravinder to begin with, my query doesn't sort questions relevance, then it should find resu_id from 'point' table then sort them by point.

Comment: Check out my updated query, and plz  revert beck if anything more is required...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for relevant result data, you can try the following query:

```
select 
   p.ques_id, p.resu_id, p.point,
--   q.question,
   r.result -- , p.pont_id
from
   result r
   inner join point p on ( r.resu_id=p.resu_id )
--   inner join question q on ( q.ques_id=p.ques_id and q.ques_id=? ) -- // use this if required
   inner join question q on ( q.ques_id=p.ques_id )
order by 
   q.ques_id, p.point desc, r.result desc
;
```

Output of the above query execution:

```
+---------+---------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| ques_id | resu_id | point | result                               |
+---------+---------+-------+--------------------------------------+
|       1 |       7 |    10 | located on the continent of Europe   |
|       1 |       1 |     8 | Germany is located in Europe         |
|       2 |       6 |    10 | 52 degrees North, 13 degrees East    |
|       2 |       7 |     7 | located on the continent of Europe   |
|       2 |       3 |     4 | between France & Poland              |
|       3 |       5 |     9 | South of Denmark                     |
|       3 |       4 |     8 | Germany is located in central Europe |
|       3 |       2 |     6 | Northern hemisphere in Europe        |
+---------+---------+-------+--------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Remove the fields from `select` whichever you don't want to select again.

Comment: thank u, but it should return results with the highest point. I've added "expecting result" on my question above.

Comment: thanks, you're a life saver. but in which part you sort the question?

Comment: @bekman Sorting is done using `order by` clause. `order by 
   q.ques_id, p.point desc, r.result desc`

Comment: what i mean is where does exactly "german location" compared with the questions listed on the example. are we supposed to use "%like%" or "similar_text" ?

Comment: @bekman No. `german location` text content is irrelevant here. As you already have entity relation defined, comparing the text was not required.

Comment: Main purpose was to match and give most related questions and their best results respectively. that is why i started my question with "Germany location". is it possible? or should i use another technique? thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't advise to depend on such practice. Because 1. text `Germany` may also be present in many other questions and 2. Result text may not be having text `Germany`. So we can't decide relevancy based on text presence. You should rely on entity relation only.

Comment: you're right, i thought about it, there are lots of steps before it reaches to this query, any modification on your code? like if "Germany location europe" gives ques_id '3' '1' '2' and their best result.

Comment: No alteration to my answer. Because, search by part of text and by noun and verb form is not at all possible with the data objects available.

Answer (score 0):

I believe u want this ::

```
  SELECT result 
  FROM Result 
  inner join Point on (Result.resul_id=Point.resul_id)
  WHERE Point.ques_id = ? ORDER BY Point.point desc limit 1
```

Comment: This only returns single row with the highest point result id, which perhaps denotes the correct answer to the question id.

Comment: Is OP looking for the first record of the results?

Comment: Thank you Sashi, but that's not what i am looking for, as Ravinder said it only returns one result but what i want my query to accomplish is to return all results based on question similarities then their respective result sort by result point.

Comment: This will give the result u need :::: 

SELECT result 
  FROM Result 
  inner join Point on (Result.resul_id=Point.resul_id)
  WHERE Point.ques_id = ? ORDER BY Point.ques_id asc, Point.point desc